# I can't remove the data from the tree node it just shows when I view it again

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary-tree

```
def delete(self,data):
    if self.root!=None:
        self._delete(data,self.root)
def _delete(self,data,cur):
    if cur!=None:
        if cur.data==data:
            if cur.left==None and cur.right==None:
                cur=None
            else:
                print("Wait")
        else:
            self._delete(data,cur.left)
            self._delete(data,cur.right)
```

I am using recursion in the code to delete the leaf node from a tree but putting cur=None is not doing anything it prints the the node when I view it again.

Comment: `cur=None` only sets the local `cur` variable to None. It doesn't set any attribute of your object to `None`. `cur` is a separate local variable.

Comment: You should read [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: You need to re-assign the nodes in the tree after the function returns. For example, if you delete the root, you need to set the `self.root = None`, and that is not what `cur=None` does